# does someone have a solution to "Could not start Build & View:PdfLaTeX"

Tags: pdftex, miktex

I work with Windows 10, Miktex and pdflatex.
Furthermore my GUI is Texstudio. 
I recently updated Texstudio to the newest version. A week ago everything worked fine, but today I wanted to compile a .tex file which aborted. I could track down the problem to the package `sgame`, but that's another story now.

I tried restarting my computer - failed

after looking at my settings and not finding anything suspicious I reinstalled Texstudio - I might have done something wrong, but no.
Then I updated Miktex, even reinstalled it.

I even changed my settings - great mistake - and now pdftex and/or miktex do not work properly anymore.

Unfortunately I cannot find a solution to my problem.

Error Message when compiling:

```
Could not start Build & View:PdfLaTeX:
"C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/x64/pdflatex.exe" -synctex=1 - 
interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

My .log file

```
The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

C:\Users\Markus\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\initexmf.log

2018-12-20 15:10:34,947+0100 FATAL pdflatex - The memory dump file could not     be found.
2018-12-20 15:10:34,947+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Info: fileName="pdflatex.fmt"
2018-12-20 15:10:34,947+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Source:     Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\texmfapp.cpp
2018-12-20 15:10:34,947+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 690
2018-12-20 15:10:34,947+0100 INFO  pdflatex - finishing with exit code 1
2018-12-20 15:10:42,165+0100 INFO  pdflatex - starting with command line:     "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode texstudio_a13436.tex
2018-12-20 15:10:42,181+0100 INFO  pdflatex - allowing known shell commands
2018-12-20 15:10:42,181+0100 INFO  pdflatex - enabling input (output) from (to) processes
2018-12-20 15:10:42,212+0100 INFO  pdflatex - going to create file: pdflatex.fmt
2018-12-20 15:10:49,852+0100 ERROR pdflatex - C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\initexmf.exe did not succeed; exitCode: 1
2018-12-20 15:10:49,852+0100 ERROR pdflatex - output:
2018-12-20 15:10:49,852+0100 ERROR pdflatex - 
Sorry, but "MiKTeX Configuration Utility" did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

C:\Users\Markus\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\initexmf.log

2018-12-20 15:10:49,852+0100 FATAL pdflatex - The memory dump file could not be found.
2018-12-20 15:10:49,852+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Info: fileName="pdflatex.fmt"
2018-12-20 15:10:49,852+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\texmfapp.cpp
2018-12-20 15:10:49,852+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 690
2018-12-20 15:10:49,852+0100 INFO  pdflatex - finishing with exit code 1
```

My commands are:

LaTeX

```
latex.exe -src -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

PdfLaTeX

```
"C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/x64/pdflatex.exe" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

Default Compiler:

```
txs:///pdflatex
```

Unnecessary minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

    Hello World

\end{document}
```

After running `initexmf --dump=pdflatex` on cmd I got following results:

```
Sorry, but "MiKTeX Configuration Utility" did not succeed. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: 
C:\Users\Markus\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\initexmf.log
```

The initexmf.log file says:

`2018-12-20 16:09:11,743+0100 INFO initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.6811 (MiKTeX 2.9.6840 64-bit) 2018-12-20 16:09:11,743+0100 INFO initexmf - Operating on the private (per-user) MiKTeX setup 2018-12-20 16:09:11,743+0100 INFO initexmf - starting with command line: initexmf --dump=pdflatex
2018-12-20 16:09:11,743+0100 INFO initexmf - running: miktex-makefmt.exe --engine=pdftex --dest-name=pdflatex --no-dump pdflatex.ini --engine-option=-tcx=cp227.tcx --enable-installer 2018-12-20 16:09:19,015+0100 ERROR initexmf - sub-process error output has been saved to 'C:\Users\Markus\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\miktex-makefmt_2018-12-20-160919.out'
2018-12-20 16:09:19,015+0100 FATAL initexmf - The process terminated due to an access violation. 2018-12-20 16:09:19,015+0100 FATAL initexmf - Info: fileName="C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-pdftex.exe" 2018-12-20 16:09:19,015+0100 FATAL initexmf - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Process\win\winProcess.cpp 2018-12-20 16:09:19,015+0100 FATAL initexmf - Line: 475`

Comment: "The memory dump file could not be found." means that miktex couldn't create the format file. No tex file can be compiled without it. Open a command line and run `initexmf --dump=pdflatex` and hope that it gives some info in the case of failure.

Comment: What does the `miktex-makefmt_2018-12-20-160919.out` file says? (and better edit your question instead of adding all this info to the comments)

Comment: Access violation doesn't sounds good. Ensure that your miktex is up-to-date (check for updates in user and admin mode) and if the problem persists add a bug report to the miktex issue tracker at github.

Comment: thx for your help.